# How to Connect via SSH to GitHub from codesion.com?

Tags: ssh, github

I want to "Publish" from Codesion to Github but even when the SSH-Key is Passphrase-less and everything works locally perfect the codesion server can't connect to github, why?

In other words I want to publish-connect to github from codesion, the SSH-key works perfect and it is Passphrase-less but no matter what codesion server never connects to Github, why?

Please look at attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzcgm.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe adding the PEM envelope might help `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` ... `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`